# logic operations on multidimensional arrays in verilog

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, verilog, logical-operators

I have a multidimensional array as below.

```
reg [3:0] varname [`KEY-1:0];
```

I want to check if atleast one element in the array is equivalent to 4'b1111 or 4'b1110

What is the easiest and best way we can do this?

Comment: Need to know if you want this to be synthesized, and if so, how big is `KEY`?

Answer (score 1):

If 'KEY is small and constant that you know, then it is better to use simple logic for each row (example for i-th row)

```
if((varname[i] && 4'b1111) || (varname[i] && 4'b1110) )
```

If 'KEY is variable or quite large number then it is better to use different method, i would try using

```
output reg equivalent_detected;
reg counter;
initial
begin
     equivalent_detected = 1'b0;
     counter = 0;
end

always@(posedge clk)
begin

if((varname[counter] && 4'b1111) || (varname[counter] && 4'b1110) )
     equivalent_detected <= 1'b1;
counter <= counter + 1;

end // end of always block
```

You can use the above codes in your module
If you use equivalent_detected as your output then whenever you get 1 it means you detected 4'b1111 or 4'b1110.
You can further improve this code and make it better, I just wanted to give you some idea.

Comment: since OP does not care about the lowest bit, you can simplify it: `varname[counter][3:1] == 3'b111`

Comment: The conditional logic is incorrect, it should be `varname[counter] == 4'b1110` (or the simplification @Serge suggested) since `varname[counter] && 4'b1110` will evaluate to true so long as `varname[counter]` is not `4'd0`. You should note that your design also takes `\`KEY` clock cycles to complete since OP didnt specify whether or not this is a synchronous design at all.